# Adaptive cards text not searchable on teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We've built an Escalation Teams bot which posts an adaptive card into a Channel. When trying to search(using search at top of teams) for any text on the cards, nothing is returned. Is there a way to search Teams for adaptive card content? [AdaptiveCardExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAL5D.jpg) Trying to search for text in the example [TeamsSearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRGqW.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're right, I didn't realise this and just tested my side to confirm. I'd suggest logging it as a request on [uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/). As a possible solution, perhaps offer a "search issues" capability inside the bot itself, to search it's own DB?

Comment: Down the line we plan to create a QNA knowledge base whereby the Issue itself and resolution are stored. Will raise like you suggested.

Comment: Was wondering if you had that in mind. I assume you've seen QnAMaker.ai?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible. May be in future this search behavior will be updated.